# How to Add Image/Sprite on Texture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am drawing background Sprite

1) CCRenderTexture...draw texture using it

2)The taking sprite from this

So i need to add some images or sprite(from images) on to the texture..

so is there any API by which we can add to texture and then getting sprite (texture + images)..

or i have to draw on texture using open gl commands???

Thanks in advance

Comment: to which engine is your question related? It can't be about cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android, and cocos2d-x at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCRenderTexture is a CCNode. As with every CCNode you can just add sprites as children and position them wherever you want. For animation to them you can use CCAnim just as with any other sprite.